# Script de leitura rapida no python3?

Tags: python-3.x

alguem conhece algum script para python3, que faça com que eu cole um texto qualquer no programa, e ele leia de linha em linha numa determinada velocidade, exemplo  Aprox.WPM:5000 (5000, palavras por minuto)?
Agradeceria muito.

Comment: Você está solicitando um programa pronto ou possui alguma dificuldade para implementar o que necessita?

Comment: Queria um programa como exemplo, para ver o script e fazer alguns testes, se tiver como, ou só a funçao para importar. Tem alguma ideia?